# Getting the percentage of a variable in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to get the percentage of a variable. Here's the exact assignment:

> Write a program in Python that, of a list of words stored on each line
>   of a text file, prints and counts the number of long words, i.e words
>   that have more than 10 characters and indicates the percentage of long
>   words, given the total amountg of words in the text file.

And here's my code:

```
wordcount = 0
longwordcount = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    charnum = len(line)
    wordcount = wordcount + 1
    percentage = int(longwordcount // wordcount) * 100
    if charnum > 10:
         longwordcount = longwordcount + 1
         print(line)



print("There are {0} words in the word list that have more than 10 characters.\nThis is {1}% of the total number of words in the text file." 
.format(longwordcount, percentage))
```

Comment: Count the number of words. Count the number of *long* words (all in the same loop). **At the end**, when you have counted everything, calculate the percentage.

Comment: For starters, `sys.stdin` is not ideal. Better off defining the path, or using `sys.argv[1]`, and open/read using `with open() as...`.

Comment: `int(longwordcount // wordcount) * 100` is zero times 100, or 1 times 100. You probably mean `longwordcount * 100 // wordcount`. And you should calculate it at the end, not as you go.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `//` here (see above comments)  but if you really want to want try something like this. 
`percentage =  (100 * longwordcount) // wordcount`

Comment: Ahh right, I can work with that! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the division operator instead of the floor division operator and not the int type conversion.  You can use your format statement to limit the number of digits if desired.

percentage = longwordcount / wordcount * 100